# Fat Burning Zone -- Is it real?

Tags: medical-science

Does low-intensity, long-duration exercise really "burn fat" at rates higher than highly aerobic exercise?  Is the academic case for this view actually strong?  It seems like a lot of accepted knowledge in the exercise industry has a weak scientific basis.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From the [American Council on Exercise](http://www.acefitness.org/blog/39/i-ve-heard-that-performing-aerobic-workouts-at-a/):

> In a **30-minute aerobic exercise**:
>
> **Low Intensity** (50% of maximum exercise capacity):
>   - you'll burn approx. **200
>   calories, 120 of them from Fat
>   (60%)**
>
> **High Intensity** (75% of
>   maximum exercise capacity):
>  - you'll burn approx. **400 calories, 140 of
>   them from Fat (35%)**

So,

> **while it is true that a higher
>   proportion of calories burned during
>   low-intensity exercise come from fat**
>   (about 60 percent as opposed to
>   approximately 35 percent from
>   high-intensity programs),
>   **high-intensity exercise still burns
>   more calories from fat in the final
>   analysis**.

---

[Dummies.com](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/busting-the-great-myths-of-fat-burning.html) concurs:

> ... working at a lower intensity
>   requires less quick energy and a
>   higher percentage of fat is burned.
>   But you'll also burn fewer calories
>   than you would if, for the same amount
>   of time, you work out at a harder
>   intensity (e.g. running versus walking).
>
> During the same amount of time you
>   don't use more calories at lower
>   exercise intensities.
>
> **If you're trying
>   to lose weight and you have only 30
>   minutes to work out, you would burn
>   fewer calories walking at a moderate
>   pace compared to walking at a fast
>   pace.**

The conclusion is:

> **Working out at higher
>   intensities may cause you to burn a
>   lower percentage of fat, but since you
>   burn more total calories, you still
>   use more fat calories.**

Comment: More sources on this: http://scienceblogs.com/obesitypanacea/2010/06/the_myth_of_the_fat_burning_zo.php

Comment: Does that mean the extra calories burned from high-intensity are from muscle?

Comment: So, if one is fat, wants to lose it, does not have a lot of $ to buy extra food, and has all the time in the world (e.g. a homeless person), then they should just walk around all day instead of running for a couple of hours.

Comment: don't forget that the low intensity workout can be maintained for longer than the high intensity workout, especially by untrained people. So someone's who's not in a great physical shape might be able to do the 30 minute low intensity workout, but no more than 10 minutes of the high intensity workout. He's thus better off doing the low intensity workout as his benefit per session is improved. The conclusion from dummies.com is of course false. "you burn less fat, but because you burn more you burn more fat anyway" is logically wrong. The rest which gets burned is protein and carbohydrates.

Comment: @jwenting -  you are right, for someone who is not very fit a long low-intensity workout could be more beneficial than a short high-intensity one. The 'Dummies' conclusion is for a 30-minutes workout, even though the 'fat percentage' is lower, the 'total' amount ends up being higher. (But, in a short workout the low-intensity would indeed burn more fat)

Comment: yes, more fat over time, not more fat as a percentage of total calories burnt (which would require twice the time on the low intensity workout). I was counting for a equal total energy consumption, they're talking about equal time spent.

Comment: @KallDrexx - Apart from fat the other usual source of calories during exercise is sugar or blood sugar, or more specifically [glycogen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glycogen).

Answer (score 6):

Looks like you are right and the fat burning zone is a bit of a falicy. To quote [this research](http://www.colorado.edu/intphys/Class/IPHY3700_Greene/TIPS/exIntesity/Tremblay.pdf):

[image]

And they also have this table to show the results:

[image]

At 9 times the fat burning power of low intensity exercise I know what i'm going to be doing to lose weight!

** Edit **

I guess I need to clarify this.  The study above is trying to debunk some of the conventional wisdom about the fat burning potential of exercise regimes.  Two regimes were run, a low intensity study programme (ET) and a high intensity study programme (HIIT).

To add another table from the link study:

[image]

looking at the bottom row of the table, you can see that the ET group lost (ignoring the +/- to make the math easier) 4.5 subcutaneous skinfolds, whereas the HIIT group lost 13.9 subcutaneous skinfolds.

The ET programme resulted in more total time working out and used 120.4 +/- 31.0 MJ of energy.
The HIIT programme resulted in less total time working out and used 57.9 +/- 14.4 MJ of energy.

Or from a percentage point of view the HIIT group did roughly 48%  (57.9/120.4 for the percentage) of the work that the ET group did, but the people on the HIIT study lost more body fat (note that average overall weight loss was virtually non-existant for both groups).

If you now take that 48% and extrapolate it up to 100% it works out at an equivalent subcutaneous skinfolds loss of 28.99 (13.9/0.48), this equates to about 6.5 times as much subcutaneous skinfold loss.  Now i'm not a mathmatician, and I have only taken one row on the table into account without taking any standard deviations into account the the above workings out are going to be messy and inaccurate, but they should hopefully illustrate the point.

High impact workouts are better at reducing body fat than low impact workouts and the point of this study was to debunk the conventional wisdom given by health professionals.

Comment: me too: I am going to sit on a couch watching TV with sandbags in my lap and throw one on the floor occasionally.

Comment: Note: It says *relative to the energy costs*!

Comment: This is a perfect example of how studies are not read carefully, and then some extraordinary claims are based upon this. The relative fraction of energy from fat is higher in the fat burning zone, but the total number of calories burnt is much lower. See the other answer on this.

Comment: I think I misread your answer. Especially your final sentence had me fooled. I'll remove my downvote asap.

Comment: hmm what did you think I meant?  Seems like a got a lot of flack for this one.

Comment: Added some more to clarify it some more, basically the study is trying to debunk some of the advice given out by health professionals. I think we may be looking at the question from different angles as well.  I'm looking at it from the following angle:

if you do 30 mins of exercise, what will burn more fat, low impact or high impact.

I think you are looking at it from the angle of:

Comment: If I excercise what give me a higher percentage of fat burn?  Low impact or high impact?

You could say we are both right but arguing different points of view.

Comment: yes. Higher percentage of a lower total burn per hour. Main question is could someone keep up the high intensity workout as long as the low intensity workout? Probably not unless they have no fat left to burn :)

Comment: Probably not, but the results show that they don't really need to.  They can lose more body fat by doing a shorter (in time period) high intensity workout as shown by the figures above.